# pH measurement in cascaded tanks -- Ground loop

Tags: ground, ground-loop, ph

I am doing a mini waste water plant with cascaded PVC tanks (and PVC fittings) for my university project. Each tank has a mixer (the motor is grounded). I made a pH amplification PCB which works with its own battery then send wirelessly the information to my computer.

I was advised that it could be a ground loop, I trace the supposed path on the graphic. Near 1 unit of pH error in the 2nd tank if I compare with a sample taken in a beaker. The error seems proportional to the water flow.

What could be the best approach to solve the issue? Independent PCB for each pH-meter? ground electrodes like stainless steel faraday cages around electrodes connected both together? Or even connected together and with the negative pole of the battery?
[image]

Comment: Most likely the error is a common mode rejection or range error with your bridge amp or sensor error.  Show all details with links to spec sheets

Comment: is it 59.16mV / pH unit ? with temp. compensation?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I am using LMC6482 as opamp with unity gain followed by an ADC working -1  to +1V with 16 bit resolution.

Comment: By putting linked faraday cages around the electrodes, it seems that problem is fixed, the offset error is gone - I have still to try in process conditions. Next time I will use only one opamp/battery per electrode. I didn't implemented T°C compensation because working near 7. I will check mV per pH unit.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is having the same problem, I found a solution:
Both electrodes cannot share the same ground, a ground loop forms between each reference electrode of both pH meter. Each pH meter must have its own ground (own current generator or use a DC-DC isolated converter).